# How can I get all post records on my MERN app?

Tags: node.js, backend, nodes, mern

I am working on a MERN App and this is a basic project in which we allow users to login and create posts from their account and user can follow other users and on the homepage they can see their posts along with posts from their friends as well.

Below I have shared the code to get all posts on the homepage. I have created an admin panel in which I want to get all posts from the database (MongoDB Atlas). I have allowed the admin to delete any post but right now admin has to visit every profile to delete posts I want to show all posts on a single page to make it easy for the admin to delete any post.

Following is the code to get posts for my homepage

```
//get timeline posts

router.get("/timeline/:userId", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const currentUser = await User.findById(req.params.userId);
    const userPosts = await Post.find({ userId: currentUser._id });
    const friendPosts = await Promise.all(
      currentUser.followings.map((friendId) => {
        return Post.find({ userId: friendId });
      })
    );
    res.status(200).json(userPosts.concat(...friendPosts));
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: I mean what problem are you currently facing? Your code seems fine but you should prevent the DB calling from the loop. It would be better If you use an aggregate query . Here the link you check https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/aggregation-with-user-preference-data/

Comment: the above code is working just fine but I want to write another code similar to this to get all posts because with above posts i can only get posts of friends

Comment: I assume you can use `Post.find({})` to get all posts, but you will probably want to paginate it in some fashion. Does this library/driver give you an API to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understant clearly your problem. But if you need to get all your posts here a solution:

```js
const posts = await Post.find().lean(); // you will get an array of posts
```

Comment: router.get("/allposts", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const posts = await Post.find().lean();
    return res.status(200).json(posts);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});